# Ellipsis on text contained in a flex item sized by flex-grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, ellipsis

I Have a single row, using flexbox, which contains cells.

I wish that the text of the first cell to be on  a single line and truncated with an `ellipsis`.
Everything as to remain responsive.

However using the classic css trick :

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Applies only if the parent element containing the text have a fixed `width`.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell cell1">
        Some long-text
        long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-long-
    </div>
    <div class="cell cell2">cell-2</div>
    <div class="cell cell3">cell-3</div>
    <div class="cell cell4">cell-4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

  .cell {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
  }
}
```

How can I only define the size of my cells using `flex-grow` + `flex-basis` and also manage my single line truncated text ?

Comment: add min-width: 0

Answer (score 0):

You can make this modification to your css:
Add `overflow: hidden` to all cells to ensure that text overflow is hidden and
add `white-space: nowrap` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` only to the .cell1 class to truncate the text in the first cell.
Here's the code below:

```
     .row {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;

        .cell {
          flex-grow: 1;
          flex-basis: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
      }
      .cell1 {
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
```